# FUSE camel + KIE Execution Server integration POC

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, jbossfuse, kie

Recently, I am starting to look at Fuse Camel, Drools WB and Kie Execution Server Integration for a new project and I am having the following problem.

I am using Fuse 6.2, Drool 6.2.Final for WB and Kie Server.

This is what I have done:

1. create the Person Drink drool rule from the Fuse Example in Drools-WB and deployed in on the Kie Execution Server using my own Containers : myCheese.
2. in Fuse Camel, instead of calling the internal Kie-Camel Server,  I am using a bean in which setup the header for Comel-jetty to fire the rules :

   public void populateRestHeader(Exchange exchange) {

   ```
   // hard code the message for time being because   BatchExecutionHelperd doesn't work. please see below.
   ```

   String myMessage = "<batch-execution lookup="ksession1"> "
   + "<insert out-identifier="person" > <org.drools.camel.example.Person> john "
   + "51 </org.drools.camel.example.Person>  "
   + " ";

   ```
   // setup the login token
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("Authorization", basicToken);
   // POST so I can send XML.  GET works fine !
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "POST");
   // the content
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.ACCEPT_CONTENT_TYPE, "application/xml");
    exchange.getIn().setBody(myMessage);
   ```

   }
3. POST the commands to remote Kie-Server using jetty :

   jetty:http://my-server/services/rest/server/containers/myCheese
4. On the Kie-Server log, I am getting :

15:19:33,140 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-114) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: Cannot consume content type
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:380) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:114) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]

Either the "Content-Type" wasn't setup correctly or the body wasn't sent ?

5. I tried to perform a GET using the same method and this works out nicely !

Received :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><response type="SUCCESS" msg="Info for container myCheese"><kie-container container-id="myCheese" status="STARTED"><release-id><artifact-id>mycheese</artifact-id><group-id>com.markit</group-id><version>1.0</version></release-id><resolved-release-id><artifact-id>mycheese</artifact-id><group-id>com.markit</group-id><version>1.0</version></resolved-release-id><scanner status="DISPOSED"/></kie-container></response>
```

6. Using SoapUI to execute the command without any problem.

```html
<response type="SUCCESS" msg="Container myCheese successfully called.">
<results><![CDATA[<execution-results>
  <result identifier="person">
    <org.drools.camel.example.Person>
      <name>john</name>
      <age>51</age>
      <canDrink>true</canDrink>
      <alive>false</alive>
      <sex></sex>
      <happy>false</happy>
    </org.drools.camel.example.Person>
  </result>
  <fact-handle identifier="person" external-form="0:1:866416565:866416565:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT"/>
</execution-results>]]></results>
</response>
```

Questions :

a)  Any ideas why the error ?  Is it correct to set the Exchange.Body as the DATA for the POST ?
b) Instead of using Came-Jetty to POST the commands to Kie-Server, as Kie-Server declare it as REST, can I use CXFRS to do this ? Also, I believes Kie-Server also supports SOAP, but what is its WSDL ?   Another other alternatives ?

c) For the BatchExecutionCommands, I was planning to use the following :

```
public String createCommand() {
    BatchExecutionCommandImpl command = new BatchExecutionCommandImpl();
    final List<GenericCommand<?>> commands = command.getCommands();
   
    Person person = createTestPerson();

    commands.add(new InsertObjectCommand(person, "myPerson"));
    commands.add(new FireAllRulesCommand());
    command.setLookup("ksession1");

    String myXMLMessage =     BatchExecutionHelper.newXStreamMarshaller().toXML(command);
    return myXMLMessage;
}
```

But  I am getting the Exception in the Fuse log as :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.drools.core.runtime.help.impl.BatchExecutionHelperProviderImpl not found by org.kie.internalapi [281]
  at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1556)
  at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:77)
  at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1993)
```

Seems like Kie-Internal Package couldn't access the Drools-Core  bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

Arr.. got half of the answer. I needs to set the

Exchange.ContentType = "application/xml" !

now works nicely between the Fuse server and remote Kie-server.  However, I am still having the problem with the BatchExecutionHelper Exception.